# How to resolve a proxy error in a reactjs/ express app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have the following error:

> Proxy error: Could not proxy request /AppManager.jsx See
>   https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for
>   more information (ECONNREFUSED).
>
> react-dom.development.js:199 GET http://localhost:3000/List.jsx 500
>   (Internal Server Error)

I am using an app based on create-react-app. The app talks to a express/ node api server. Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to white list your cross domain url in express.

Here's a simple middleware function to serve up the correct CORS header from a whitelist. Setting this near the top of your express app will allow all your routes to set the proper header from the whitelist before serving up content.

```
 app.use(function(req, res, next){
 var whitelist = ['localhost:4000', 'localhost:3000', 'anydomain.com']
 var host = req.get('host');

 whitelist.forEach(function(val, key){
  if (host.indexOf(val) > -1){
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', host);
  } 
})

next();
});
```