# Facing a Proxy error while building a react application

Tags: reactjs, package.json

> Proxy error: Could not proxy request /logo192.png from localhost:3000 to http://127.0.0.1:5000/.
> See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED).

I am facing the above problem even after making the following modifications  in the package.json file

```
"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000/"
```

How to fix the error?

Comment: Dear Adrish, is your question same as this one - https://stackoverflow.com/q/53863366/465053? It has an answer. Can you please try if that answer in the other thread works for you?